# freebsd10 disc cloning

Tags: hard-disk

I have a FreeBSD 10.1 computer whose disc is failing. I've tried to use Clonezilla, and dd with no results.My syntax with dd was dd if=/dev/hda of=/dev/hdb bs=1M (I used dd on systemrescue). The version of Clonezilla was 2.12.43. I'm assuming that I'm missing something.

Thank you.

Comment: More details, please.  What did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?

Comment: I would like the disc to act exactly like the original disc. I want to be able to disconnect the failing one and replace it with the 'cloned' one. I have just tried to manually create the normal three partitions for the new disc, and use a 'dump' piped to restore to create the ufs partition. I am stymied as to how to create the boot partition. I have unsuccessfully tried to use bsdlabel to copy the boot partition to the new disc.